# Is Boogiepop series connected to the Boogie music genre?

Tags: boogiepop

Looking up the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boogie), the definition of "boogie" is:

> A style of blues played on the piano with a strong, fast beat.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogie_(genre)) it is defined as:

> Boogie (sometimes called post-disco) is a rhythm and blues genre of electronic dance music with close ties to the post-disco style

As I am unfamiliar with the genre, I tried a few sample of boogie music. I don't really see it matches the atmosphere of the anime (neither the 2000 nor 2019 adaptation). Boogiepop himself "seems fond of whistling the prelude to Wagner's Die Meistersinger von Nürnberg" which is also not related to boogie genre.

Also I don't see it too related to pop genre either.

Comment: Haven't watched this yet and I think you just answered your own question? The only thing I could find was that Boogiepop inspired other manga, anime and/or light novels. I also found in google searches that Boogiepop was inspired by Jojo but I can't verify as to why a certain article says so: https://manga.tokyo/anime-review/1st-episode-anime-impressions-boogiepop-and-others/

Comment: Considering the introduction of "*When I detect adversity approaching, I float to the surface. That's why I am Boogiepop – phantasmal, like bubbles*", I think it's more of this ["boogie" (1st definition)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boogie#Noun) which gets ["popped" (2nd or 7th definition)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pop#Verb)... not following the series at all, so I don't know...

Comment: I it more likely comes from boogeyman

Comment: @AkiTanaka I only watched anime, so that's from the novel? Could you put it as an answer?